# My mother language is Arabic and the second language is English

Tags: british-english

1: Why are the four seasons in small letters, while the days of a week and the months of a year are in capital? (summer vs Monday)

2: What is the difference between the possessive case and the genitive case?

3: What is this case called? The long-legged man. The white-faced girl...

4: Why do we use -ing after to in this case:  I am looking forward to seeing...

5: What is this case:  You are a good boy. Aren't you?

Comment: One question at a time.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please visit the help center for guidance on how to post a question. Our sister site ell.stackexchange.com would probably be more appropriate for some of your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Question 1: As much as we may be tripped up about it, the seasons are common nouns, not proper nouns, and are therefore not capitalized.

However, there are exceptions:

1. If your first name is summer, you write it with a capital "S" because peoples' first names are always proper nouns.
2. If the season is the first word in a sentence, capitalize it, as the first letter of the first word of every sentence is always capitalized.
3. If the season is part of a title, like Winter Olympics, you should capitalize it. Titles are proper nouns, which require capitalization.

Question 2: I'm not sure; someone else can probably answer.

Question 3: I'm not sure what case you're referring to in your example phrases.

Question 4: Verbs that end in -ing are present participles, which are a type of verb tense. The girl/boy is currently looking forward to seeing somebody. Another verb tense you may be familiar with is past tense. Examples of past tense are "looked," "ate," "talked," etc.

Question 5: Again, I'm not sure what case you're referring to.

Answer (score 0):

1. think the last commenter gave a good explanation for your first question.
2. You can use these interchangeably.
3. compound adjectives
4. I think you're asking why it is 'seeing' and not 'see'. The 'to' here isn't actually part of an infinitive construction. It's a preposition and the preposition here would be followed by the gerund (ing) form.
5. The 'aren't you' is probably a negative tag (if this is your question). An affirmative comment has a negative tag and a negative comment has a positive tag. Conventionally it would be written with a comma: you're a good boy, aren't you? Depending on the situation and the tone of voice it could also be a negative question where the speaker is looking for assurance.